# Inserting link to icon fonts in Nativescript

Tags: android, ios, nativescript, truetype

I'm using icomoon as my font icons. I have inserted the icons into my app but I now want to attach a link to open the browser. I tried to use a "tap" attribute with the utils function to open a browser like this:

home-page.js file

```
var vmModule = require("./home-view-model");
var utilityModule = require("tns-core-modules/utils/utils");

function pageLoaded(args) {
  var page = args.object;
  page.bindingContext = vmModule.mainViewModel;
}
exports.pageLoaded = pageLoaded;

exports.onPeripheralTap = vmModule.mainViewModel.onPeripheralTap;

exports.launch = function(){
  utilityModule.openUrl("https://www.facebook.com/ZoneFirst/");
}
```

xml-file

```
<StackLayout orientation="horizontal" horizontalAlignment="center" width="auto" height="auto">
                             <Label text= "&#xea91;" class="icon-facebook" paddingTop = "30" tap="launch"/>                         
                             <Label text= "&#xea96;" class="icon-twitter"  paddingTop = "30" paddingLeft = "20" />
                             <Label text= "&#xea9d;" class="icon-youtube"  paddingTop = "30" paddingLeft = "20"/>
                             <Label text= "&#xeac9;" class="icon-linkedin" paddingTop = "30" paddingLeft = "20"/>
                            </StackLayout>
```

css-file

```
 .icon-facebook {
  font-family: "icomoon";
  /* content: "\ea91"; */
  font-size: 42;
  color: #3B5998;
}

.icon-twitter {
  font-family: "icomoon";
  /* content: "\ea96"; */
  font-size: 42;
  color: #1DA1F2;
}

.icon-youtube {
  font-family: "icomoon";
  /* content: "\ea9d"; */
  font-size: 42;
  color: #c4302b;
}

.icon-linkedin {
  font-family: "icomoon";
  /* content: "\eac9"; */
  font-size: 42;
  color: #0077B5;
}
```

However, I realized that the tap attribute doesn't work on a Label component just a Button component. Any suggestions on attaching links to my icon fonts?

Comment: Nevermind. The above did work just fine. For some reason I had to recompile a second time before seeing it function. I hope this helps others though!